# Is it possible to query json data stored in blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob

If we store json data in azure blob storage. Can we query the json in blob storage?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but will need to leverage an azure compute service that integrates with blob storage.

The low code option here is Azure Logic Apps, which has good integration with blob storage, json capabilities and has different ways of being invoked.